# Xamarin Android Url image get request receiving 403 error but not on iOS

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android, imageview, android-imageview

I am working on an xamarin app that has images stored in an S3 bucket. The querying works correctly in xamarin when using the correctly constructed Url:

```
https:// + BucketName + path + ".jpg?AWSAccessKeyId=keycode&Expires=expireNumber&Signature=signatureCode"
```

When using 
`Image.Source = urlAddress` (as the above format) 
The image is loaded fine

Part of the apps pages have custom renderers with Images that need to be rendered via url address. We are updating the images via url at each os level. The iOS is working correctly using the following code:

```
using (var url = new NSUrl(uri))
using (var data = NSData.FromUrl(url))
      if (data != null)
            return UIImage.LoadFromData(data);
```

Which successfully gets the image from Url and updates it. However I am having major issues having it work on Android. I have tried the following area:

making a basic android url and setting the imageView with the following code. Which has been explained to not work here https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/4323/image-from-url-in-imageview

```
Android.Net.Uri url = Android.Net.Uri.Parse(url);
```

imageView.SetImageURI(url);

On that same link using WebClient was suggested by user 'rmacias' to download the data via the url and parse the bytes to an android Bitmap.

```
private Bitmap GetImageBitmapFromUrl(string url){
```

`Bitmap imageBitmap = null;`

```
 using (var webClient = new WebClient())
 {
      var imageBytes = webClient.DownloadData(url);
      if (imageBytes != null && imageBytes.Length > 0)
      {
           imageBitmap = BitmapFactory.DecodeByteArray(imageBytes, 0, imageBytes.Length);
      }
 }

 return imageBitmap;}
```

This returns a 403 forbidden error. at the line `var imageBytes = webClient.DownloadData(url)`
However the same process is working in iOS, the string is already authenticated and I have set the authentication timeout for several minutes incase of slow load. I have also tiued the same url requesting method with the `.Net.Http` library. 
It crashes at `res = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();` with the same 403 Forbidden error.

I have tried multiple things with header authentications for the WebClient and Http client. It feels that its something specific about android requesting url data because the authentication in the url string works for the Xamarin images and in the ioS code.

I'm thinking there is something specific to android that I am missing? Help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about using HttpClient, which can leverage the platform specific HttpClientHandler's which Xamarin provides?

So something like:

```
// make sure to reuse your HttpClient instance, it is a shared resource
// using it in a using() and disposing it all the time, will leave
// sockets open and bog down the connection!
private static HttpClient _httpClient;

public async Task<byte[]> GetImageDataAsync(string url)
{
    if (_httpClient == null)
    {
        // you could inject AndroidHttpClientHandler or NSUrlSessionHandler here...
        _httpClient = new HttpClient();
        // set headers etc...
    }

    var response = await _httpClient.GetAsync(url).ConfigureAwait(false);
    if (!response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        return null;

    var result = await response.Content.ReadAsByteArrayAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
    return result;
}
```

Then you can use this platform agnostically like:

```
var data = await GetImageDataAsync(url);
imageBitmap = BitmapFactory.DecodeByteArray(data, 0, data.Length);
```

on iOS

```
var data = await GetImageDataAsync(url);
var imageData = NSData.FromArray(data);
imageBitmap = UIImage.LoadFromData(imageData);
```

There are also nice libraries, such as FFImageLoading, which support this out of the box, with effects, loading of images in TableViews etc., which you can consider as an alternative.

Comment: Great it works, thank you! Seems to work fine with my pre-authenticated url-string (therefore no headers etc. needed).